# CopyOf2DArray (Values Only)

Tags: array, vba, excel

---

**Purpose:**
Given a 2-Dimensional Array, return a **copy** of the Array. In VBA, if I just

```
Set newArray = oldArray
```

then `newArray` is simply a pointer to `oldArray` rather than an independent copy, hence this function.

---

**Method:**
Assign Array bounds. Create identically-sized Array. Iterate over Array and copy each element value.

---

**Specific Areas of Interest:**
The function feels very generic. The naming even more so. But then again it's *supposed* to be very generic. Is the naming alright or could it be better?

---

**Function:**

```
Private Function CopyOf2DArray(ByRef targetArray As Variant) As Variant
    '/ Will error if the array contains objects

    Dim LB1 As Long, UB1 As Long
    Dim LB2 As Long, UB2 As Long
    AssignArrayBounds targetArray, LB1, UB1, LB2, UB2

    Dim newArray As Variant
    ReDim newArray(LB1 To UB1, LB2 To UB2)

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LB1 To UB1
        For j = LB2 To UB2
            newArray(i, j) = targetArray(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    CopyOf2DArray = newArray

End Function
```

Comment: I must be missing something. If you want a direct copy of `oldArray` then `newArray = oldArray` . No setting or redimming or looping required. What your `CopyOf2DArray` would be good for (with some minor modifications) is creating a **transposed** copy of `oldArray` that does not have the unsigned int limitations that the native Transpose does. See [my_2D_Transpose(a1 As Variant, a2 As Variant)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451126/error13-in-excel-vba-in-data-file/29456245#29456245).

Comment: @Jeeped beat me by a couple of minutes - I went the long route to verify a simple assignment is fine.

Answer (score 6):

I am going to challenge your premise

> ...then `newArray` is simply a pointer to `oldArray` rather than an
>   independent copy.

The following code works fine ...

```
Sub myTest1()
Dim oldArray() As Double, newArray() As Double
Dim i As Long, j As Long

ReDim oldArray(0 To 1, 0 To 2)
For i = 0 To 1
    For j = 0 To 2
        oldArray(i, j) = (i * 10#) + (j * 1#)
    Next j
Next i

newArray = oldArray

For i = 0 To 1
    For j = 0 To 2
        Debug.Print i, j, newArray(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

To verify that `newArray` is not just a pointer to `oldArray`, the following code ...

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function VarPtrArray Lib "VBE7" Alias "VarPtr" (Var() As Any) As LongPtr

Sub myTest2()
Dim oldArray() As Double, newArray() As Double
Dim i As Long, j As Long

ReDim oldArray(0 To 1, 0 To 2)
For i = 0 To 1
    For j = 0 To 2
        oldArray(i, j) = (i * 10#) + (j * 1#)
    Next j
Next i

newArray = oldArray

Debug.Print "oldArray", VarPtrArray(oldArray), VarPtr(oldArray(0, 0))
Debug.Print "newArray", VarPtrArray(newArray), VarPtr(newArray(0, 0))

End Sub
```

... generates this result ...

```
oldArray       1633360       350127888 
newArray       1633356       350126600
```

All of which means that, for arrays that do not contain objects, a simple assignment (e.g. `newArray = oldArray`) is fine to copy an array.

Comment: Ha! See my recent comment to the original question (not very old at all!) :)

Comment: Huh. TIL. Now I'm wondering where I got the idea in the first place. Probably a false extrapolation of object behaviour.

Comment: Why does it matter if the arrays contain objects? The arrays actually contain pointers to the objects, so `newarray = oldarray` works regardless of whether the arrays are value-types of objects.

Comment: @Zak - I think early versions of VBA may not have allowed this simple assignment. [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm) says as much. Not sure if/when this may have changed.

Comment: @ThunderFrame - I wasn't able to take the time to demonstrate to myself that this would work with an array of objects. So you may be (probably are) correct.

Answer (score 4):

Am I missing something? Why were you using `Set newArray = oldArray`? Arrays are not objects, so you can copy them using a normal assignment:

```
Sub TestLongArray()

  Dim a(1, 1) As Long

  a(0, 0) = 900
  a(0, 1) = 901
  a(1, 0) = 910
  a(1, 1) = 911

  Dim b() As Long
  b = a

  Erase a
  Debug.Assert b(0, 0) <> a(0, 0)

End Sub

Sub TestVariantArray()
  Dim c(1, 1) As Variant

  c(0, 0) = 900
  c(0, 1) = 901
  c(1, 0) = 910
  c(1, 1) = 911

  Dim d() As Variant
  d = c
  Erase c
  Debug.Assert d(0, 0) <> c(0, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry ThunderFrame - you spent about 8 minutes too long creating your excellent answer. :)

Comment: Huh. TIL. Now I'm wondering where I got the idea in the first place. Probably a false extrapolation of object behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Although the code isn't Excel-specific in any way, since this is tagged [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) there's a way to do this without even needing to iterate anything - this is probably far from perfect, but something like this anyway:

```
Private Function CopyArray2D(ByRef source As Variant) As Variant
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Dim redraw As Boolean
    redraw = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    sheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(source, 1), UBound(source, 2)).Value = source

    CopyArray2D = sheet.UsedRange
CleanExit:
    If Not sheet Is Nothing Then RemoveSheet sheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = redraw
    Exit Function
CleanFail:
    Debug.Assert False
    Resume CleanExit
End Function

Private Sub RemoveSheet(ByVal sheet As Worksheet)
    Dim alerts As Boolean
    alerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    sheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = alerts
End Sub
```

Of course there's a cost associated with creating and deleting a worksheet, so for smaller 2D arrays it's possible the nested loops outperform it. But gut-feeling tells me the array dump would be \$O(1)\$, while the nested loops is certainly \$O(n)\$.

And as a bonus you don't have to worry about numbered, abbreviated variable names :)

> ```
> '/ Will error if the array contains objects
> ```

Note, it will *also* error if the `targetArray` is *not* an array. I like that `targetArray` makes it pretty unambiguous what type you're expecting there, but "target" seems off, and makes it look like it's the return value - and the fact that the array must be passed `ByRef` reinforces that impression. Hence I'd go with `source` more than `target`. And since the function already says "I'm copying an array", then the unambiguous `fooArray` semi-Hungarian name (would you call a parameter `fooString` or `fooInteger`?) is actually redundant - so `source` would be sufficient and unambiguous to me.

`CopyOf2DArray` sounds a bit weird: you're using `Copy` as a *noun*, not a *verb*. Hence I'd put the `2D` at the end and get rid of the `Of`, making `CopyArray2D`, which is more succinct.

Comment: If you don't mind the new array being 1-based, use `newarray = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Excel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(oldarray))` and it will work with 2D **and** 1D arrays, and it doesn't require any overhead.